# WPF Apply Style to Child Controls of a user control

Tags: wpf, templates, styles

I have a WPF user control which has several labels (created dynamically) in it. I want to set the style of those labels (every label should have same style) from my user control.

So in simple terms setting the style of user control should apply that style to all its labels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is possible to declare a style for Label's in UserControl Resources and bind Setters values to UserControl properties, e.g.:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication3.UserControl1"
             x:Name="Uc1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                    Value="{Binding Foreground, ElementName=Uc1, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>            
        <Label Content="123"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

This way changing UserControl Foreground will affect all Labels inside (if they don't override Foreground setting)

Style can use Type name (`Label`) as a key and will be applied by default. Or it can have some other key and should be assigned explicitly to dynamically created Labels

Answer (score 1):

In the UserControl.Resources you can set something like:

```
<Style TargetType="Label">
     <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#112233" />
</Style>
```

As long as you do not give the style a x:Key element then it will be applied to all child Labels in your UserControl.